# cannot ssh from linux to windows machine

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I have a linux computer which I am comfortable using ssh to get into other linux devices on the same router.

What I want to do is ssh into my work computer, which is connected via an ethernet cable, and I want to be able to do this from any network my laptop is on.

I have installed openssh on my windows machine and started the server successfully.

Trying to ssh using:

```
ssh -p 2222 <WINDOWS IP ADDRESS>
```

results in a time out. I think this is happening because

a) the linux machine and windows machine are on different networks
b) the windows machine is connected via ethernet.

are there any considerations to take, other than specifying the port (which is open). I can ssh from my linux machine to another linux machine by typed `ssh <IP ADDRESS>` when on same network, so not a problem with my linux machine - and using my windows machine i can ssh into a private server (using both openssh and putty).

What do I need to do?

I can locally ssh into the windows machine. An interesting find from this is that when I use my own windows machine to ssh locally, I am presented with my @.

I therefore tried putting the username before the windows machine's public IP address like this:

```
myuser@137......
```

and tried to get in form my linux machine - it says `connection refused on port 22`. I guess this is something only our network manager can remedy - unlikely given I'm trying to ssh through a university network

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a rule in the Windows Firewall for both the input and output connection on port 22.
It's in the advanced parameters of the Windows Firewall -> Rule of incoming traffic (I'm translating my french version here) -> Right click and New rule -> Port -> TCP -> Local specific port (22) -> Accept connection -> Then validate